# I want to create a user registration from react and firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Im working in a project and im using react and firebase for that.
I want to create a user registration , I can use firebase authentication with google or facebook. but thats not what I want.
I want to take many data from the user and let that data appear on their profile.
so can I do that with react and firebase. ?
can we use firebase as a database to store users data?

Comment: yes you can do it with firebase

Comment: sure, it's possible with react & firebase

Comment: This type of question tends to not do well on Stack Overflow, because it's rather broad. However, if you search for the exact same thing in a search engine of your choice, you'll find lots of good tutorials to get you started: https://www.google.com/search?q=create+a+user+registration+from+react+and+firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I usually do is creating a "profiles" collection.
A profile document's ID is the User ID and contains more data i.e. email. I create the profile document after the firebase auth register function is done and I have the register user object.

You can also put that logic in a cloud function if you need security.

Answer (score 0):

An user have an UID (unique id) when he logs in to your app.
You can store the uid in the database and then link other infos to it. You can get it with `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`

Take a look at [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#uid)